# File system contents sometimes not synced in some bash terminals

Tags: linux, bash, sync, hard-drive-cache

I've sometimes noticed this behavior on one machine (Ubuntu using Mate terminal).

Case 1

I have 2 terminals open on the same path. I do a 'ls' on both but the output is incorrect in one of them, some files are missing as if it points to an older state of that dir.

Case 2

I do a cat on a file in that dir, first time on its relative path, second time on absolute one and the outputs are different, in one of the cases being old content.

Aside from that the terminal behaves correctly on the surface. It goes away if i reopen the misbehaving terminal but nevertheless it's annoying as i can inadvertently and unknowingly find myself in an incorrect file system state, as if sometimes it reads file system data from an unsynced cache. I can't connect this to any specific operation I'm performing.

Comment: The same problem on Unix & Linux SE: [*`ls` sees different files in the same folder on the same machine in two different terminals. How is this even possible?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713031/108618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hypothesis

Someone or something moves (renames) directories.

---

#### Explanation

What you described can happen when the directory is moved (renamed) and a new directory created. Consider this scenario:

1. In one shell create a directory, enter it, create few regular files, check them, see where you are:

   ```
   # shell 1
   mkdir /tmp/dirA &&
   cd /tmp/dirA &&
   echo foo >file1 &&
   echo bar >file2 &&
   touch file3 &&
   ls -i &&
   pwd -L &&
   pwd -P &&
   echo Success.
   ```

   The output will be like:

   ```
   335212 file1  335213 file2  335214 file3
   /tmp/dirA
   /tmp/dirA
   Success.
   ```

   This shell is in `/tmp/dirA`.
2. From another shell move `dirA` out of the way, create a new `dirA`, enter it, create few directory entries, check them, see where you are:

   ```
   # shell 2
   mv /tmp/dirA /tmp/dirA.old &&
   mkdir /tmp/dirA &&
   cd /tmp/dirA &&
   cp -l ../dirA.old/file1 ./ &&
   echo baz >file2 &&
   ls -i &&
   pwd -L &&
   pwd -P &&
   echo Success.
   ```

   The output will be like:

   ```
   335212 file1  335219 file2
   /tmp/dirA
   /tmp/dirA
   Success.
   ```

   This shell is also in `/tmp/dirA`.

Both shells see `file1` with the same inode number. They see `file2` with different inode numbers (and different content). The first shell sees `file3`, the second shell doesn't.

Also run `ls -id . /tmp/dirA /tmp/dirA.old` in both shells.

The truth is the first shell is in the directory that is now `dirA.old`, but *the shell is not aware the name has changed*:

```
# shell 1
ls -i &&
pwd -L &&
pwd -P &&
echo Success.
```

`pwd` is a builtin in Bash, the output will be like:

```
335212 file1  335213 file2  335214 file3
/tmp/dirA
/tmp/dirA
Success.
```

But `pwd` *executable* will tell you something else:

```
# shell 1
/bin/pwd -P
```

It will tell you `/tmp/dirA.old`! Additionally:

```
# shell 1
cat ./file2
cat /tmp/dirA/file2
```

will print `bar` and `baz` from two different files.

---

#### "Fix"

- You can make the first shell acknowledge it's in `dirA.old` by `cd`-ing to what `/bin/pwd -P` tells you:

  ```
  # shell 1
  cd "$(/bin/pwd -P)"
  ```
- Xor you can `cd` to the current `dirA`:

  ```
  # shell 1
  cd .
  ```

  While `cd .` here looks like a no-op, it will actually change the directory.

Note if the now-current directory is renamed again then the confusion will start again.

---

#### Solution

Identify who or what renames directories, make it stop; or do not work in directories that are about to be renamed and the old name reused.

Or maybe it's enough to change some workflow. E.g. if there is a backup script that moves some source directory and re-creates the source by copying back, consider copying from the source to the destination, without modifying the source directory at all.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply but I can't see how this is the case unless I'm missing something. I'll try to rephrase: it's as if sometimes (rarely) one terminal somehow exists in a different point in time and that is reproducible in the sense that if I do say a cat in it multiple times the same wrong data are *consistently* displayed. LIke that terminal sees old, maybe unflushed contents. All this while in another terminal everything works fine.

Comment: @user3671607 You emphasized "consistently", but in my scenario `cat`s do print consistently. I'm not saying the scenario is what happens in your OS. I'm saying IMO your observations do not prove the scenario is not what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry but I reread your initial post 2 times and I can't understand how it can explain my problem. How is it that one terminal behaves correctly at the same moment the other one seems stuck in the past?

Comment: @user3671607 The answer contains snippets of shell code to run in two separate shells and to recreate the problem. Have you tried to recreate this way and compare to your actual case?

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. For some reason I was convinced that in my case there's nothing that can move and recreate dirs but upon further reflection it looks like it's actually the case. Nice to find out about built-in pwd vs /bin/pwd and "cd ." This solved my problem, thanks!